# Dynamic "Where" clause in wpdb->prepare query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In the form, none of the inputs are mandatory. So, I want to have a dynamic "where" clause inside the wpdb query.

Presently this is the query:

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM 
`wp_gj73yj2g8h_hills_school_data` where
`school_zipcode` = %d AND `school_type` = %s AND `school_rating` = %s 
;",$selectedZip,$selectedType,$selectedRating));
```

if a user enters only school_zipcode then the where clause should have only "school_zipcode" column.
Same way for other combinations.

Comment: Use if else and in condition use isdefined like if (isdefined($school_zipcode)){your code} and do the same for others..simple

Comment: I am having four inputs, there will be 16 set of queries. Won't it affect performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not make things complicated with dynamic where clauses... I would write PHP code which creates the query. For example...

NOTE!! THIS CODE IS NOT TESTED ON SERVER, IT'S JUST AN IDEA HOW TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM!

```
<?php
$where_query = array();

// Make sure to escape $_POST
if (!empty($_POST['school_zipcode')) {
  $where_query[] = "school_zipcode='" . $_POST['school_zipcode'] . "'";
}

// Make sure to escape $_POST
if (!empty($_POST['school_type')) {
  $where_query[] = "school_type='" . $_POST['school_type'] . "'";
}

// Should result in WHERE school_zipcode='123' AND school_type='text'
$where_query_text = " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $where_query);

$data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wp_gj73yj2g8h_hills_school_data` " . $where_query_text  . ";"));
```

Comment: Careful! sql injection attack waiting to happen here.

Comment: This is an outright dangerous answer (SQL injection) and should never ever be done.